# How to invoke webservice defined in grails application from php

Tags: php, web-services, rest, grails

I am newbie to webservices

I have a domain class as below in my app.

```
class Training{

  string name
  Date date

}
```

and i want to display the list of training in php page

**What changes i have to make in grails and in php script to do this.I want the data in JSON format.**

And I want to follow the RESTful architecture.

Basically I want to interact with grails app from my website (written in php). In future i want to do save the data from my website to grails app DB and many calls.

And Do i need to authenticate before serving the request in webservice.

Comment: Creating a web service in Grails is covered in [the Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#REST). Calling a web service is making a web request and does not depend on what framework implements the web service. Finally whether or not to have authentication is a design decision based on your security needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow the architectural pattern see following link: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#REST

First create you TrainingController controller which performs the requested action and returns the json data. e.g.

```
class TrainingController {
   def show = {
      render Training.get(params.long('id')) as json
   }
}
```

if you don't use a special url mapping to match the restful pattern, you can simply call training/1 and get the json structure returned. See the documentation for more rendering options.

Comment: How to call grails webservice method remotely means outside of grails app by using jquery and html from another server

Comment: if you want to call this controller action from another server using jquery, i would recommend to use jquery.ajax() function. see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.